# How to search file in windows

Tags: windows, search

I want to search a file in which there is a text as "hello user " , how i can search it using command prompt or with any other method ? i want that file anyhow please help me

I tried eveything to acheve the result but didn't work

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow amit! isn't this kind of question better to be directed off to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)? it does not involve you writing any code after all. anyway, please take a [tour] and learn [ask].

Answer (score 1):

use sublime, vscode editors to open that folder in which files are located. use ctrl+shift+f to search the text into that files